# How to display only the first occurrence of an item in a set on a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am learning Django, so this might not be the best way to do what I want.

What I am trying to do here is to display an item that has been selected multiple times in a cart, only once (and the number of times it has been selected next to it)

I have been all day trying to find a way but the closest thing I managed to do is, inside the views, to produce two sets: single_items, and multiple_items.

I have no problems displaying an item which has been selected only once, but when it comes to items selected multiple times I can only display them n times with the number of occurrences next to it, as shown in the picture

[image]

Although I would rather do all the calculation with python code (in views.py) a solution with Django template language will do to me.

Please consider that I need to pass the item ID in the url in order to make the remove link to work.

here is views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .models import Cart, Item, CartItem
    from django.db.models import Sum


    # Create your views here.
    def home(request):
        items = Item.objects.all()
        carts = Cart.objects.all()
        length = len(Cart.objects.all())
        cart = carts[length - 1]
        cart_items = cart.items.all()
        total = cart_items.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
        if total is None:
            total = 0
        number_of_items = cart_items.count()
        deletable_items = CartItem.objects.all()

        occurrences = None
        single_items = set()
        multiple_items = set()
        for deletable_item in deletable_items:
            occurrences = deletable_items.filter(item__name=deletable_item.item).count()
            if occurrences > 1:
                deletable_item.occurrences = occurrences
                multiple_items.add(deletable_item)
            elif occurrences == 1:
                deletable_item.occurrences = occurrences
                single_items.add(deletable_item)

        return render(request, 'cart/home.html', {'cart': cart,
                                                  'items': items,
                                                  'cart_items': cart_items,
                                                  'total': total,
                                                  'number_of_items': number_of_items,
                                                  'deletable_items': deletable_items,
                                                  'multiple_items': multiple_items,
                                                  'single_items': single_items,
                                                  'occurrences': occurrences
                                                  })


    def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
        item_id = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
        carts = Cart.objects.all()
        length = len(Cart.objects.all())
        cart = carts[length - 1]
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(item=item_id, cart=cart)
        return redirect(home)


    def remove_from_cart(request, item_id):
        item_to_remove = CartItem.objects.get(id=item_id)
        item_to_remove.delete(

)
    return redirect(home)
```

and my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Restaurant</h1>
<div><h1>Menu</h1></div>
{% for item in items %}
<ul>{{ item }} £{{ item.price}} <a href="{% url 'add_to_cart' item.id %}">Add</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
<div><h1>Order</h1></div>
{{ cart }}
<br>
<h2>items selected: {{ number_of_items }}</h2>
{% for single_item in single_items %}
<ul>{{ single_item }} x {{ single_item.occurrences }} <a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' single_item.id %}">Remove</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
{% for multiple_item in multiple_items %}
<ul>{{ multiple_item }} x {{ multiple_item.occurrences }} <a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' multiple_item.id %}">Remove</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
<h2>Total</h2>
{{ total|floatformat:2 }}
</body>
</html>
```

and just in case the models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='CartItem')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order number: %s' % self.id


class CartItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)
```

EDIT

at the moment I am using this view.py which has been suggested by Willem Van Onsem

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Cart, Item, CartItem
from django.db.models import Sum, Count, F


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    items = Item.objects.all()
    cart_items = Item.objects.filter(
        cartitem__cart=cart
    ).annotate(
        ncount=Count('cartitem')
    )
    total = cart_items.aggregate(total=Sum(F('price') * F(float('ncount'))))['total']
    context = {
        'items': items,
        'total': total,
        'cart_items': cart_items
    }
    return render(request, 'cart/home.html', context)


def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    item_id = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    carts = Cart.objects.all()
    length = len(Cart.objects.all())
    cart = carts[length - 1]
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(item=item_id, cart=cart)
    return redirect(home)


def remove_from_cart(request, item_id):
    item_to_remove = CartItem.objects.get(id=item_id)
    item_to_remove.delete()
    return redirect(home)
```

Comment: Well the problem is that you each time count the number of items. But these are *different* `CartItem`s, hence the `set(..)` does *not* see these as different ones.

Comment: I think you want to say that set() does see them as different ones, and that's why duplicates are allowed (they are different objects with the same name attribute)

Comment: What is `carts[length-1]` doing? If there are multiple users, they will see the last cart, and thus one user will see the cart of the other user.

Comment: because two persons that both have `Mirko` as first name, are *not* per se the same persons.

Comment: is just to get the last cart (order) created...

Comment: That's the thing. I don't think the problem here is set(), I could have used a list. What I am asking for is if there is a template filter or tag that allows showing only one occurrence in a template iteration (if makes sense)

Comment: please do *not* solve such problems at the template level. A template only should render content nicely. You should *not* implement business logic in a template.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better here to develop two querysets like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Sum

def home(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    items = Item.objects.all()
    cart_items = Item.objects.filter(
        cartitem__cart=cart
    ).annotate(
        ncount=Count('cartitem', output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0))
    )
    total = cart_items.aggregate(total=Sum(F('price') * F('ncount')))['total']
    context = {
        'items': items,
        'total': total,
        'cart_items': cart_items
    }
    return return render(request, 'cart/home.html', context)
```

In your template, you can then render the cart with:

```
<h2>items selected: {{ cart_items|length }}</h2>
{% for item in cart_items %}
    <ul>{{ item }} x {{ item.ncount }} <a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' item.id %}">Remove</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
<h2>Total</h2>
{{ total|floatformat:2 }}
```

so there is no reason to make a distinction between objects that are bought once, or multiple times.

You can implement the remove function with:

```
def remove_from_cart(request, item_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    item_to_remove = CartItem.objects.filter(
        item_id=item_id,
        cart=cart
    ).delete()
    return redirect(home)
```

Comment: Wow, that's way shorter :) I am trying your solution (and will study something more about queries as I am not at this level yet) but it returns an error about 'ncount'. I have also tried to change it to 'count' but it seems I will have to create an attribute 'count' in the model to make it work. is that right?

Comment: @MirkoOricci: sorry, I made a typo, it should be `cart_items.aggregate(..)`.

Comment: Yep, seems to be better, but it returns 'Expression contains mixed types: DecimalField, IntegerField. You must set output_field.' now. I guess I'll have to find a way to convert 'ncount' to decimal, right?

Comment: @MirkoOricci: yes that should be something like `Cast(..)`.

Comment: mmm... if I try to cast price and total into integers, it says that is impossible because they are in base 10, and if I try to cast ncount into a float number it says that it's impossible to parse the string into a float number...

Comment: @MirkoOricci: A string? I find it rather odd, since a `Decimal` is something different than a `float`, and `Count` uses by default an `IntegerField`.

Comment: @MirkoOricci: can you edit your question, and share what you exactly tried?

Comment: OK, I was doing it in the wrong manner. I have found the Cast() function that you suggested, and I think it should look something like Cast('ncount', output_field=FloatField), but I don't know where this code should go. I tryied to add it with a dot after you declare ncount as '.........ncount=Count('cartitem').Cast('ncount', output_field=FloatField())' but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MirkoOricci: no, there is no `.Cast(..)` method, it is an expression. But we probably do not need it anyway. What Django version are you using?

Comment: I am using the 3.0.2 version

Comment: @MirkoOricci: what if you use `ncount=Count('cartitem', output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0))`?

Comment: It works :) but clicking on the remove link returns 'CartItem matching query does not exist.'

Comment: I have printed a few things for testing purposes and basically what's happening is that every time I add an item to the list, I actually create it, so I have now id that is around 400 something, but when I click on remove I only have 3 IDs...got to figure out how to tackle this now

Comment: @MirkoOricci: what if you alter it with the given `remove_from_cart`?

Comment: @ WillemVanOnsem: i am not sure if that's what you are asking, but I tried to alter the number in the url (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/remove/408) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the selected items in the database even before the user checks out, which I would not advice, then you can make something like this in the models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    #model info


class Order(models.Model):
    item = modelS.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = modelS.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    times = models.IntagerField(default=1)
    #..... other relevant fields

class Cart(models.Model):
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order)
    user = modelS.ForeignKey(User,related_name='cart_user' on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other details like date etc....
```

then a view that checks if the a model already exist

```
def add_order(request,id):
    user = request.user
    item = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    try:
       order = Order.objects.get(item=item, user=user)
       order.times+=1
       order.save()
    except:
      order = Order.objects.create(
             item = item,
             user = user
            )
     try:
         my_cart = Cart.objects.get(user=user)
     except:
         my_cart = Cart.objects.create(user=user)
     my_cart.orders.add(order)

   #return http reeponse with the new data
```

I would advise you to use ajax to submit the request to the url that calls the view to update so as to make less page refresh in future

Comment: Thanks kim, I will check your answer as well. As I said I am just learning Django and I only know Python at a fair level. I was trying to build a project that keeps things minimal. Of course I will encounter Ajax, Javascript and also Django sessions, but at the moment I'd rather do the things as easier as I can.

Comment: Thanks, will be a long one for sure :)

Comment: not much, soon as you start to get this things you`ll know they are simple

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach: Why don't you add a Field to CartItem model in your models.py called "quantity" or something like that? For example:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And then in your add_to_cart view, you'd do:

```
def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    cart_item_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(cart__pk=cart.pk)
    if cart_item_qs.exists():
        cart_item_qs.update(quantity=F('quantity') + 1)
    else:
        cart.items.add(item)
        cart.save()

    return redirect(home)
```

After that, you can have in your template the instance of CartItem model passing it in the context data and therefore access the quantity field value from there.